# Adding border style to <tr> not wokring

Tags: css, html-table, gridjs

[image]

Is this feature available with gridjs or I am not putting it in right place as expected by Api?

Comment: You might want to share your complete code, see here-- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set borders to a `tr` - apply them to the `td` elements instead (and use `border-collapse: collapse` on the `table` element to avoid double borders optionally)

Note: On the `td`s, use `border-top` and/or `border-bottom` to avoid vertical borders between the cells, also `border-left` on `td: first-child` and `border-right` on `td: last-child` to have vertical borders on the outsides.

Comment: Thanks for help. 
Also, I have multiple grids on same page with formatters applied almost in every cell. Each grid doesn't have more than 10 rows.
After the complete load, the tables become unresponsive if I perform sorting on them.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

in order for the border style to work, you have to have `border-collapse: collapse;` in the table element's CSS